# Android error on Attempt to invoke virtual method; I don't understand it

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to build a simple navigation drawer, but I keep getting this annoying error. I am fairly new to Android so I really don't know how to fix/what it means. Any help is appreciated.

Java:

```
package com.google.helpstl2;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class Home extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private String[] planets;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, planets));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this,planets[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Relevant XML?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Logcat error output is :

```
Process: com.google.helpstl2, PID: 2205 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.helpstl2/com.google.helpstl2.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: post your LogCat output

Comment: Thanks for the answer:     Process: com.google.helpstl2, PID: 2205
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.helpstl2/com.google.helpstl2.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: it seems that your `ListView` is null, check if the id `drawerLayout` really exists in your Activity's layout

Comment: The id is definitely there, but thanks

Comment: @JacobPlatin: are you sure ListView is in `activity_main.xml` layout?

Comment: @JacobPlatin oh sorry, I mean the id `drawerList` of course. The `listView` field being null is the only reason for the error log you have posted. Try to add `if (listView != null)` before setting the adapter

Comment: @Droidman Thank you! I realized my Java file was set to activity_main and not activity_home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your xml layout file with content :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

is not `activity_main.xml` so you are getting NPE when finding id : `drawerList`

Check this thing one time.

You can add null check at the error line :

```
if(listView != null ) {    
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, planets));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized my Java file was set to activity_main and not activity_home